# Why does my tray always disappear when I open a new window in FF or IE?

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer

Whenever I open a new window - whether it is in Firefox on IE - my tray always disappears. Why is it so? It seems to be some wrong setting with my tray.

Comment: *Tray?* As in Windows task bar maybe? Or the location bar in the browser itself?

Comment: Tray? System Tray / Notification Area?

Comment: The blue line in the vary bottom of my screen, I don't know how it is called correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking on your taskbar, select Properties and turn off Auto-Hide.